# Is the Scholomance weight allowance for baggage only?

Tags: scholomance

There are a couple of references throughout *A Deadly Education* to the induction process that brings pupils into the school.

Specifically in chapter 3 it says you can buy extra weight for mana:

> throw away thirty filled power sinks for an extra quarter-kilo.

In chapter 13 the new freshmen arrive and here we get a couple of suggestions that body weight doesn't count, with youngsters that have gorged on goose grease (metaphorically) and a girl with protection charms braided into her hair.

Does the scholomance give a weight allowance like an airline for baggage content, or do lighter inductees get to bring more stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the books are not explicit here, I think we can reason by contradiction that the weight allowance does not depend on the weight of the students.

Survival is an absolute priority at the Scholomance, meaning that people send their children with as many useful items as possible. It is mentioned many times that a fraction of a kilogram of weight is so valuable that no one would willingly give it up without getting *something* in return; for instance, when El's mother sends her a letter, the former thinks that the latter must have done something important for the mother of the boy who brought it to her, since he had to forgo a squeeze of magical toothpaste. Being able to bring several kilos more due to a lower body weight would be priceless.

Therefore, if the students' own weight mattered, we would see first year students starved until they were as thin as possible without making them a weakened target for the maleficaria. No one would come to school with any hair: they would all shave. To be frank, people would probably remove their kidneys, pieces of their liver, or any other less-than-completely essential organs so they could bring that one extra power crystal.

We never hear about any of this, even though it would be logical to mention say, that the first year students were all bald and starved. Therefore, we can safely conclude that the students' weight is likely not taken into account.

Comment: Absent word of God, this seems a reasonable summation.